# Does LLDP packet traverse switches?

Tags: switch, lldp

I have some nodes (An) connected to switch A and others (Bm) connected to switch B.

Should Bm nodes receive LLDP packets from switch A?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

802.1AB defines several (3) multicast addresses for LLDP that a compliant switch should not forward.

That said, an unmanaged switch with no specific handling for multicast will very likely treat LLDP (and any multicast traffic) as broadcast and spam it to every port.

Comment: So, is it possible to prevent LLDP packets from traversing other switches (Switch B in my example) and arrive to other nodes (Bm) knowing that I have no access to the physical connection of the switches?

Comment: If your switch is passing LLDP, then it is **100%** incapable of being configured to stop it. (almost certainly because it isn't configurable *at all*)